# Search for Text, Apply Background Colour in Multiple Cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can anyone explain to me how I adapt this working code so that it can do these two different things:
1) Also select the cell below the one with the found text and apply the same background colour to the new cell too.
2) Also select the cell below the one with the found text and apply the colour to the font.

```
Sub ScratchMacro()
Dim r As Range
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim wdOrange As Long
Red = 255
Purple = 16711875
Black = 0
Pink = 11796735
Blue = 16711680
Orange = 41215
Green = 1954333
Yellow = 60671
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
With r.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="The Text You are Searching For", MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True)
      If r.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        If r.InRange(r.Cells(1).Range) Then
        r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Yellow
        End If
      End If
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: `r.Cells(1).font` ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. The code I have posted works for the "FOUND TEXT CELL" but I would also like to apply the "r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Yellow" to the table cell BELOW the one found with the text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to get the row and column index from the "found" cell, increase the row index by one and use that to identify the cell in the table.

Note that it's a good idea to place `Option Explicit` at the top of all code "pages", which means all variable names need to be declared. I use that, so all those colors are "dimmed" in the code sample below.

```
Sub ScratchMacro()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim tbl As word.Table
    Dim rIndex As Long, cIndex As Long, r2Index as Long
    Dim cel As word.Cell, cel2 as Word.Cell
    Dim Red As Long, Purple As Long, Black As Long, _
         Pink As Long, Blue As Long, Green As Long, Yellow As Long

    Red = 255
    Purple = 16711875
    Black = 0
    Pink = 11796735
    Blue = 16711680
    Green = 1954333
    Yellow = 60671
    Set r = ActiveDocument.content
    With r.Find
        Do While .Execute(findText:="The Text You are Searching For", MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True)
          If r.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Set tbl = r.Tables(1)
            rIndex = r.Cells(1).RowIndex
            r2Index = r.Cells(1).RowIndex + 1
            cIndex = r.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
            Set cel = tbl.Cell(rIndex, cIndex)
            Set cel2 = tbl.Cell(r2Index, cIndex)
            cel.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Blue
            cel2.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Blue
            cel.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
          End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```